# Python function time complexity examination

Tags: python, time-complexity

[image]

Hi, i need to calculate the time complexity of this function.
Not sure how to determinate the inner loop's complexity. Might be just O(n) but i think it might be O(log(n) because of decreasing amout of loops (j appears less times in n based on i's growth). help?

Comment: why don't you test it to check? you can use the `time` module and get `startTime = time.time()` and `ExecutionDuration = time.time() - startTime` for different lengths of `L` and plot the results... Furthermore, your question does not include your attempt at solving the problem and also includes code as an image, please correct both

Comment: Please post text as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

### When you don't know, try the first iterations

...at the first iteration of the for loop, `i=1`

you enter the while loop:

```
while j<n:
j += 2
```

Let's define k as the number of iterations of this while loop. You can notice that `j = 2 * k`
this while loop ends when

```
j >= n, i.e 2k >= n, i.e k >= n/2
```

at the second iteration, same logic but `j = 2 * 2 * k` so the while loop runs `n/(2 * 2)` times.

at the third iteration, the while loop runs `n/(2 * 3)` times

#### Then generalize

...at the i-th iteration of the for loop, the while loop runs `n/(2 * i)` times

In conclusion, in the complexity calculation you have:

```
$$ C = \sum_{i=1}^{n} n/(2 * i) $$

$$ C = n/2 * \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1/i $$
```

The sum of `1/i` has a complexity of `O(ln(n))`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

### Conclude

Thus I would say the complexity of your algorithm is `O(n * ln(n))`